# GitHub Actions "User input" step

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way (perhaps custom step/job on the marketplace) that prompts the user for input in the middle of a workflow?

I know it is possible to define user input fields when the workflow is triggered manually - `workflow_dispatch` event.

However, in my environment, the workflows need to be triggered by pull requests.
The logic is something like:

- automated start
- wait for user input
- automated action based on the input

Is it possible to have a user input or survey step when the workflow is started automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to do this exact thing but github does not appear to support this as you mentioned in your post. The closest I could get is having a job that fails unless a specified label (one for true, one for false) is set. This acts as the "prompt" and setting the label acts as the "input". The "prompt" job passes once the label is set, and then you can trigger any actions based on that label.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want, you would need to have two or more workflows -- the first would run and complete and then send a notification via Slack or some other tool for the user to reply to, which would require your own custom app that talks to the GitHub API and (in this case) Slack app. Once you have the reply, you can use it as input when you trigger the other workflow using the GitHub API or a workflow call. For what it's worth, GitHub does allow you to take user inputs at the start of a workflow, and that could include something like "continue on error" or whatever it is you want them to answer.